Boosting probability of Randomized approximation algorithms
Suppose $A$ is a randomized algorithm with following properties:

The expected running time of $A$ is at most $\mathrm{poly}(n)$
When Opt$\geq c$, with probability at least $\mathrm{poly}(n)$ algorithm $A$ outputs a value at least $s$.

I want to give a randomized algorithm $A'$ which runs in $\mathrm{poly}(n)$ time with certainty with property that when Opt$\geq c$, $A'$ give a solution of value at least $s$ with probability at least $1-2^{-n}$.
The natural method with to repeat $A$ several times, hence the failure properbility is lower than $1-(1-1/\mathrm{poly}(n))^{r(n)}$ with $r(n)$ repeat, however, a question is that the running time of $A$ only has expectation $\mathrm{poly}(n)$, while we want $A'$ has certainty polynomial running time, how to solve it?

Can't you stop an execution of $A$ if it reaches, say, $2p(n)$ (where $p(n)$ is the expected running time of $A$), and ignore its return value?
